# Can i implement get in ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have images stored in buffer and referred in news. When I populate images, I need them to be as Base64 URL. Is it doable

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  images: [{ 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'File',
    get: (image) => {
      return { 
        title: image.title,
        url: `data:${image.mimeType};base64,${Buffer.from(image.data.data).toString('Base64')}`
      }
    }
  }],
  content: String,
  status: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => new Date()
  }
}, { 
  collection: 'news' 
})

module.exports = mongoose.models.News || mongoose.model('News', Schema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the schema declaration. Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents you should look up about valid types here  ([See more about SchemaTypes here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html))

I can think of two solutions.
First would be to save in `File` your images not as Buffer but as base64.

Second solution would be to convert your images after population with a map function.